# How to get package name or applicationId in gradle build script?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have moved from Ant script to gradle build script. But I don't know any way to get package name or applicationId in gradle build script.

[image: See image]

[image: See image]

Answer (score 5):

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    project.android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def applicationId = [variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId, variant.buildType.applicationIdSuffix].findAll().join()
        ...
    }
}
```

or define one in foo.gradle :

```
// foo.gradle
def appId = 'com.example.bar'
ext.appId = appId

// build.gradle
apply from: './foo.gradle'
...
defaultConfig {
   ...
   applicationId appId
}

// other.gradle you want
apply from: './foo.gradle'
...
task example {
    println(appId)
}
```

Comment: Or if you have `applicationId` inside the configuration: `print "ID: ${android.defaultConfig.applicationId}"`

Answer (score 4):

I will just repeat what @mortalis wrote because its not in answer ,but was actual answer for me, after tried some things based on answer :)

```
"${android.defaultConfig.applicationId}"
```

or

```
"${android.namespace}"
```